# Good Test Case Management Solutions for Agile with JIRA

Tags: test-management, agile-testing, jira

I know this is a subjective question, but I'm looking to find pros and cons of different Test Management Software to be able to make an objective decision to get the best tool for my needs.

I am a long time user of ALM Quality Center and like a lot of their features, but want to consider other options and price is a factor.  I am currently looking at qTest as an option that looks like it meets many of my needs.  Does anyone else have experience with these and other tools and have input into their pros and cons.

**Preferred Features**

*Good organization*

It is important to be able to organize tests by feature in a hierarchy and have good search tools to determine if a test already exists

*Version Control*

It would be useful to be able to have different versions so if there is a different software in production vs in development we can have both behaviors detailed and keep track of changes to the requirements as time goes on as well

*Reusable Test Scripts*

For easy maintainability I would like to be able to reuse test steps in different test cases so that if a part of the application changes that affects many tests, for instance a field moves to a different location, we can change one place and all tests would be updated.

*Integration with JIRA*

We are an agile company and use Jira for our stories and bugs.  It would be useful to be able to have an integration that would allow us to link these stories to our tests as a requirement reference and the bugs to executions for easy visibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider **TestRail**. Please take a look at [testrail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/) site.

Here you can maintain the Testcases, Create milestone for each execution and also you can run the test execution and also share the results to the client. Herewith you can integrate with JiRA and other softwares via API.

Comment: Please edit your answer to describe how TestRail will meet the OP's needs.

Comment: You can organize things very well with different suites, and sections within them.  Versioning is handled by doing a test run on a specific test suite, the runs cannot be changed retrospectively.  Reuseability is possible by easy copying.  And integration with Jira (and many others) is a piece of cake.  There Kate, you don't have to even look at anything on their site..

Answer (score 1):

You can even consider **Zephyr** as it provides a seamless integration and customer support is really good too. More info regarding the same would be [available here.](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.je/cloud/overview)

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Adaptavist test management.](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kanoah.test-manager/cloud/overview)

It is a JIRA addon, lower cost than most and very nicely done. It has all your preferred features. We used qTest initially, but we wanted closer integration with JIRA. We moved to Adaptavist and it has worked for us. Of course, it depends on your needs. The team that supports it is super responsive also.

Answer (score 0):

hope my answer is still valuable. We got the same issue as you in our company. We are using HP ALM but unfortunately we are facing challenges regarding JIRA. Since our project is using the agile way with tools like JIRA we want to "connect" our testing team with this agile mindset.

So what we learned is the following, we used Qtest (now called Tricentis) [https://www.tricentis.com/][1]

Why we used it or why we made the decision for it? Well we compared it with HP ALM and follwoing I can say:

**Good Organization**
This tool is really good and good organized, this also depends on building test cases in a test suite (structure and so on). As Testmanager I also saw that our Testanalyst easily used Tricentis / Qtest because of the fact that they used HP ALM (nearly same procedure for building Test Cases).

**Reusable Testscripts**
Tests can easily updated with Qtest. You cann easily add further Test steps within a test case or modify it. Nearly the same in HP ALM

**Integration with JIRA**
Integration with JIRA is possible, unfortunately we couldn´t use it because of our Firewall. We have strong restrictions in our company. But as I saw for testing purposes all test cases (when creating defects) can be connected with JIRA (for bug reporting).

But there is one more thing which HP ALM does not provide

**Exploratory testing**
This was absolutely necessary for us! Because whit Qtestexplore (like an add-on) which is only working on Chrome, you can just start your testcase in a exploratory way. Means that this is "capturing" the steps and creating step by step screenshots (also with points where you clicked it). Afterwards you can - when bug is found -directly send it to developer(e.g. as bug). And furthermore Qtestexplore "creates" test steps where you can fill in further detailed description. This was absolutely necessary for our company since we want to use the way of exploratory testing!

Hope I could help,